# Fixing a persistent issue with Visual Studio 2022 IntelliSense

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I've had something break for me in VS2022 a couple of months ago that's really annoying, and I thought "VS2022 must be broken" and tried some things (like updating it) to no avail. Now got a new laptop recently and the same issue persists, so it must be with some setting tied to my account which I can't figure out for the life of me.

Basically my Intellisense is broken. If I do "classInstance." nothing pops up (I have to do ctrl+space manually), and then when the method has overloads, there's no way I can see the overloads, I end up having to shift+f12 to see the class members and figure out the overload that way.

Comment: Here are default settings for it (for C#): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG1sT.png Do yours match?

Comment: I had "Show completion item filters" checked, rest the same. Didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed via Tools > Import and export settings > Reset all settings.

Comment: Hi Mark, since you found the solution, please [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question, this will be helpful to others who meet the similar issue and seeking for the answer. :)